# Could not Insert data into std::set. Discarded as duplicate

Tags: c++, set, std

```
struct Room
{
    int room;
    int x,y;
    int dist;
    Room(){}Room(int _room,int xx,int yy,int _dist)
    {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        room = _room;
        dist = _dist;
    }

    bool operator < (const Room& tempRoom)const
    {
        return dist < tempRoom.dist;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<Room>que;
    que.insert(Room(0,0,0,1));
    que.insert(Room(0,0,0,1));
    que.insert(Room(1,2,0,1));
    que.insert(Room(0,2,0,1));
    for(auto itr = que.begin(); itr != que.end();itr++)
        cout<<itr->room<<","<<itr->x<<","<<itr->y<<","<<itr->dist<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It shows the output 0,0,0,1. But it should be

0,0,0,1

1,2,0,1

0,2,0,1

I know its something to do with operator overloading. I tried overloading the == operator. But after searching I found set uses only < operator for any comparison. How do I modify the < operator overloaded function to achieve above output? Thanks.

Comment: How about `room < tempRoom.room && dist < tempRoom.dist` in your `operator<`?

Comment: Also, in addition to the answers below (which say more or less the same thing) - you may want to consider implementing a separate comparison object for `Rooms` - you don't really want `room1 < room2` to be a valid expression except inside the `std::set` where you are checking for equivalence. And even if you do you probably want your "external" comparison to only take into account the distance.

Comment: @CompuChip: this is bad idea: the logic you describe does _not_ define a strict weak order. You'd need to do something along lines of `room < tempRoom.room || (!(tempRoom.room < room && room.dist < tempRoom.dist)` (since the underlying comparisons provides [essentially] a total order, it may be reasonable to use `room != tempRoom.room? room <  tempRoom.room: dist < tempRoom.dist`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current less-than operator only considers the field `dist`. The ordered associative containers consider two objects `a` and `b` *equivalent* when neither `a < b` nor `b < a` yields `true`. When there is already an element equivalent to an object being inserted, the insertion will be ignored (and the `return`ed pair will point to the new element with the `first` member and use `false` in the `second` member to indicate that no object was inserted).

If you want to consider your object only equivalent when all of the members are equal, you'd use a less-than operator which simply considers all of them. The easiest way to do is to use a temporary `std::tuple` to use its less-than operator:

```
bool Room::operator< (Room const& tempRoom) const {
    return std::tie(this->x, this->y, this->room, this->dist)
         < std::tie(tempRoom.x, tempRoom.y, tempRoom.room, tempRoom.dist);
}
```

This comparison operator uses the element's less-than operator to determine the order of an aggregate of the elements. You can use any other comparison suitable, too, as long as it defines a strict weak order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation about how set check two elements are equal or not. I have another question. If I want to find a specific element with the three member variables x,y and _room_ but not with the _dist_, how do I do that? The set::find function also uses the < operator I think. If I use your < operator implementation then there are multiple same x,y,room with different _dist_. I want to erase them and keep the one with lowest dist value. Is there any way to do that? I can ask another question if this seems a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: @Tahlil: I do think this is indeed a different question. The basic approach would use the `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` members of the `std::set<...>` with suitable keys, i.e., a minimal/maximal value for `dist`. Depending on your needs it may be reasonable to create a class which keeps only the respective mininal value upon insertion. In that case the keys would only compare all but the `dist` members (and it may be reaonable to rather use a `std::map<...>` with a key which doesn't contain the `dist` and making the `dist` the value of the map).

Answer (score 3):

You only compare by `dist`, so 2 objects with the same `dist` will be equal. To fix that compare by all the things that make an object different.

Something like this:

```
bool operator < (const Room& lhs, const Room& rhs)
{
    return
        std::tie(lhs.dist, lhs.room, lhs.x, lhs.y) <
        std::tie(rhs.dist, rhs.room, rhs.x, rhs.y);
}
```

As an aside I used a non-member function for the comparison operator.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be useful in a set your `operator <` needs to consider all relevant fields, not only the `dist`:

```
bool operator < (const Room& other)const {
    return
        dist < other.dist
    || (dist == other.dist && room < other.room)
    || (dist == other.dist && room == other.room && x < other.x)
    || (dist == other.dist && room == other.room && x == other.x && y < other.y);
}
```